# How do I get metadata for a link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title><$BlogPageTitle$></title>
    
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
</head>
<body>

<div trbidi="on">

<div style="padding: 0;">
<div id="makingdifferenttimer" style="display: none;">
<div id="notes_url" style="font-family: Electrolize,lolblogger,Tahoma; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 16px;">
<div id="url_qu">
.</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="mdtimer">
<div style="font-family: Electrolize,lolblogger,Tahoma; text-align: center;">
<b>Please wait...</b>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
!function(a,b,c,d){function g(b,c){this.element=b,this.settings=a.extend({},f,c),this.settings.fontSize||(this.settings.fontSize=this.settings.radius/1.2),this.settings.strokeWidth||(this.settings.strokeWidth=this.settings.radius/4),this._defaults=f,this._name=e,this._init()}var e="countdown360",f={radius:15.5,strokeStyle:"#2E64FE",strokeWidth:d,fillStyle:"#8ac575",fontColor:"#2E64FE",fontFamily:"Electrolize,lolblogger,Tahoma",fontSize:d,fontWeight:700,autostart:!0,seconds:20,label:["second","Seconds"],startOverAfterAdding:!0,onComplete:function(){}};g.prototype={getTimeRemaining:function(){var a=this._secondsLeft(this.getElapsedTime());return a},getElapsedTime:function(){return Math.round(((new Date).getTime()-this.startedAt.getTime())/1e3)},extendTimer:function(a){var b=parseInt(a),c=Math.round(((new Date).getTime()-this.startedAt.getTime())/1e3);this._secondsLeft(c)+b<=this.settings.seconds&&this.startedAt.setSeconds(this.startedAt.getSeconds()+parseInt(a))},addSeconds:function(a){var b=Math.round(((new Date).getTime()-this.startedAt.getTime())/1e3);this.settings.startOverAfterAdding?(this.settings.seconds=this._secondsLeft(b)+parseInt(a),this.start()):this.settings.seconds+=parseInt(a)},start:function(){this.startedAt=new Date,this._drawCountdownShape(3.5*Math.PI,!0),this._drawCountdownLabel(0),this.interval=setInterval(jQuery.proxy(this._draw,this),1e3)},stop:function(a){clearInterval(this.interval),a&&a()},_init:function(){this.settings.width=2*this.settings.radius+2*this.settings.strokeWidth,this.settings.height=this.settings.width,this.settings.arcX=this.settings.radius+this.settings.strokeWidth,this.settings.arcY=this.settings.arcX,this._initPen(this._getCanvas()),this.settings.autostart&&this.start()},_getCanvas:function(){var b=a('<canvas id="countdown360_'+a(this.element).attr("id")+'" width="'+this.settings.width+'" height="'+this.settings.height+'"><span id="countdown-text" role="status" aria-live="assertive"></span></canvas>');return a(this.element).prepend(b[0]),b[0]},_initPen:function(b){this.pen=b.getContext("2d"),this.pen.lineWidth=this.settings.strokeWidth,this.pen.strokeStyle=this.settings.strokeStyle,this.pen.fillStyle=this.settings.fillStyle,this.pen.textAlign="center",this.pen.textBaseline="middle",this.ariaText=a(b).children("#countdown-text"),this._clearRect()},_clearRect:function(){this.pen.clearRect(0,0,this.settings.width,this.settings.height)},_secondsLeft:function(a){return this.settings.seconds-a},_drawCountdownLabel:function(a){this.ariaText.text(b),this.pen.font=this.settings.fontWeight+" "+this.settings.fontSize+"px "+this.settings.fontFamily;var b=this._secondsLeft(a),c=1===b?this.settings.label[0]:this.settings.label[1],d=this.settings.label&&2===this.settings.label.length,e=this.settings.width/2;d?y=this.settings.height/2-this.settings.fontSize/6.2:y=this.settings.height/2,this.pen.fillStyle=this.settings.fillStyle,this.pen.fillText(b+1,e,y),this.pen.fillStyle=this.settings.fontColor,this.pen.fillText(b,e,y),d&&(this.pen.font="normal small-caps "+this.settings.fontSize/3+"px "+this.settings.fontFamily,this.pen.fillText(c,this.settings.width/2,this.settings.height/2+this.settings.fontSize/2.2))},_drawCountdownShape:function(a,b){this.pen.fillStyle=this.settings.fillStyle,this.pen.beginPath(),this.pen.arc(this.settings.arcX,this.settings.arcY,this.settings.radius,1.5*Math.PI,a,!1),this.pen.fill(),b&&this.pen.stroke()},_draw:function(){var a=Math.round(((new Date).getTime()-this.startedAt.getTime())/1e3),b=3.5*Math.PI-2*Math.PI/this.settings.seconds*a;this._clearRect(),this._drawCountdownShape(3.5*Math.PI,!1),a<this.settings.seconds?(this._drawCountdownShape(b,!0),this._drawCountdownLabel(a)):(this._drawCountdownLabel(this.settings.seconds),this.stop(),this.settings.onComplete())}},a.fn[e]=function(b){var c;return this.each(function(){c=a.data(this,"plugin_"+e),c||(c=new g(this,b),a.data(this,"plugin_"+e,c))}),c}}(jQuery,window,document);
//]]>
</script>
<br />
<div class="time_dir" style="text-align: center;">
<div id="container">
<div id="countdown">
</div>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">var countdown=$("#countdown").countdown360({radius:90,seconds:3,fontColor:"#ffffff",strokeStyle:"#ff8000",fillStyle:"#ff4000",autostart:!1,onComplete:function(){console.log("done"),$(".download_faster").show(),$(".dowen_bum").show(),$("#container").remove()}});countdown.start();</script>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){var a=2;setInterval(function(){$("#mdtimer span").text(a--),0==a&&($("#makingdifferenttimer").delay(1e3).fadeIn(1e3),$("#mdtimer").hide(1e3).fadeOut(fast))},1e3)});
$(document).ready(function(){$(window).load(function(){var a=window.location.hash.substr(1);$("#url_qu").html("<center><b> Product link ready </b><br><br></center><a href="+a+' "." style="    font-size: 18px;font-family:Electrolize,lolblogger,Tahoma;line-height: 35px;font-weight: 600;color: #FFFF;background:#0000ff;display: table;padding: 0px 61px 0 61px;margin: auto;box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.35) inset, 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);border-radius: 30px;" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"/>Click Here</a>')}),setTimeout(function(){window.location.hash.substr(1)},11010)});
</script>
<div>
<br /></div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 


</body>
</html>
```

How do I get link metadata when shared on social media?

This is a waiting page to redirect visitors to another site link when I type the page link

Then # the link that I want the visitor to go to, waiting for the counter, then clicking on the button, it will go to the other site after the # sign

When I share the link on any social networking site, it shows metadata for the waiting page

How do I get the metadata of the link that the visitor will go to?

Comment: You make a HTTP request and parse the HTML response to find the metadata. The most important thing to note is that ***you will need to do this server side*** because you cannot reliably make a cross-domain request through client side JS.

Comment: I don't want to request metadata from the domain
This is like a link shortener that fetches the metadata of the original short link

I want to fetch the metadata for the button that the link or button goes to

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

They make a request to the link that you provide. You can see that when you use [grabify](https://grabify.link/) (here you will see the request). Then you can parse the html to get the metadata. You should make the request from the bakend and store the result, so that you dont have to reuqest the information multiple times. Also it is unlikely that the request will be allowed cross domain. You can test it by using `fetch` for example to get the google homepage like this `fetch("https://google.com/")` however this will return a `CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` error.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to request metadata from the domain
This is like a link shortener that fetches the metadata of the original short link

I want to fetch the metadata for the button that the link or button goes to